# mediaelement.js - pause/play onclick for video?

Tags: javascript, onclick, playback, mediaelement.js

What's the easiest way to add pause/play functionality by clicking anywhere in the video element similar to most video players?

I tried:

```
$('video').click(function() {

        if($(this).paused){

            $(this).play();

        } else {

            $(this).pause();

        }


    });
```

But it didn't like the $(this).pause() call. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

DS

Answer (score 4):

```
    $(".mejs-mediaelement").click(function(){
        if($(".mejs-overlay-play").css('display') == 'none'){
            $('video').each(function(){this.player.pause()});
        }
    });
```

just try it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('video').click(function() {

        if(this.paused){

            this.play();

        } else {

            this.pause();

        }


    });
```

But, this won't work.  You will want to float an invisible div (with an invisible PNG in it) over the video to receive the click commands.

Or you can use a solution like http://videojs.com/

Comment: why won't this work? i receive the click events fine so I dont see why I need a div overtop the video. i just switched from videojs to mediaelementjs as it supports audio too.

Comment: I think it has to do with it being a jquery object vs a dom object

Comment: yup that was it. need to convert to a dom element in order to access the html5 video methods.

Comment: var domObj = $(this).get(0); to convert to dom element

Comment: Yes, which is why I removed the $().  You don't need to explicitly convert it to a jQuery object.  What you have done is convert dom element->jQuery object->dom element.  Also, I'm surprised you are allowed to override video's default behavior, as if I remember correctly video implementations implemented it that way by design and there was quite a bit of controversial hoo-ha over the whole thing.  I haven't worked with video tag in a while, so things may have changed since then.